# firebase realtime database Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In here I am generating a uniqe perant in the database using uid and update some values in it,
I am trying to do some filitration based on the email to know if users exist then update the values if not then generate a new user

```
 useEffect(() => {
        const writeToDatabase = () => {
          if (location && location.coords && UserDataFromGoogleAuth) {
            const usersRef = ref(database, 'users');
            const email = UserDataFromGoogleAuth.email;
            if (email) {
              const emailRef = orderByChild(usersRef, 'email');
              const query = equalTo(emailRef, email);
              get(query).then((snapshot) => {
                const uuid = snapshot.exists() ? Object.keys(snapshot.val())[0] : uid();
                const userRef = ref(database, `/users/${uuid}`);
                const userData = {
                  id: uuid,
                  name: UserDataFromGoogleAuth.displayName,
                  email: email,
                  includedKids: 0,
                  isSubscribed: false,
                  long: location.coords.longitude,
                  lat: location.coords.latitude,
                  online: props.online,
                  profilePicture: UserDataFromGoogleAuth.photoURL,
                };
                set(userRef, userData);
              }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
              });
            }
          }
        };
        writeToDatabase();
      }, [UserDataFromGoogleAuth, location, props.online]);
```

but I am getting this error:

> ERROR  Error: orderByChild failed: path argument was an invalid path = "MY_Database_path". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

Comment: What is the `uuid` value in your code when the error occurs? From the error message it seems that it contains a character that is now allowed, so you'll have to filter or replace that.

Comment: Hello Frank, I have filtered the output of the vale but I am still getting the same error 
        const filteredUuid = uuid.replace(/[^\.\#$\[\]]/g, "");

Comment: I belive the problem that it can't find the path of the email since it reads it as a parent,
the path is like (database>users>{uuid for eachuser}>email)
but I am not sure how to pass the uuid value before the email since it's initialed after  
I this the path should be:  orderByChild(userRef, `/${uuid}/email`) ..

Comment: `orderByChild()` should only be passed a single argument that specifies the child key. You currently pass `usersRef` as the path, which when converted to a string probably results in `"[object Object]"`, thus resulting in the error. I suggest reading through https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data to see how you should use these methods.